# Why is unordered_map and map giving the same performance?

Tags: c++, performance, data-structures, unordered-map

Here is my code, my unordered_map and map are behaving the same and taking the same time to execute. Am I missing something about these data structures?

Update: I've changed my code based on the below answers and comments. I've removed string operation to reduce the impact in profiling. Also now am only measuring the find() which takes almost 40% of CPU in my code. The profile shows that unordered_map is 3 times faster, however, is there any other way to make this code faster?

```
#include <map>
#include <unordered_map>
#include <stdio.h>

struct Property {
    int a;
};

int main() {
    printf("Performance Summery:\n");
    static const unsigned long num_iter = 999999;

    std::unordered_map<int, Property > myumap;
    for (int i = 0; i < 10000; i++) {
        int ind = rand() % 1000;
        Property p;
        p.a = i;
        myumap.insert(std::pair<int, Property> (ind, p));
    }

    clock_t tStart = clock();
    for (int i = 0; i < num_iter; i++) {
        int ind = rand() % 1000;
        std::unordered_map<int, Property >::iterator itr = myumap.find(ind);
    }

    printf("Time taken unordered_map: %.2fs\n", (double)(clock() - tStart)/CLOCKS_PER_SEC);

    std::map<int, Property > mymap;
    for (int i = 0; i < 10000; i++) {
        int ind = rand() % 1000;
        Property p;
        p.a = i;
        mymap.insert(std::pair<int, Property> (ind, p));
    }

    tStart = clock();
    for (int i = 0; i < num_iter; i++) {
        int ind = rand() % 1000;
        std::map<int, Property >::iterator itr = mymap.find(ind);
    }

    printf("Time taken map: %.2fs\n", (double)(clock() - tStart)/CLOCKS_PER_SEC);
}
```

The output is here

```
Performance Summery:
Time taken unordered_map: 0.12s
Time taken map: 0.36s
```

Comment: 0.06 is pretty close to the resolution of the standard clock on most systems, so all this is saying is that both take less than one tick; multiply your outer loop by 100 or more and see what happens.

Comment: Your code doesn't actually do anything observable with the maps, so quite likely the optimizer simply removed it.

Comment: Compile with full optimization and increase the number of iterations by several powers of ten and see if that makes a difference.

Comment: You are measuring string creation and conversion time.

Comment: You should be stating up front whether you're compiling with optimizations turned on or not.  If you're compiling an unoptimized or a "debug" version, the results are meaningless.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie yes, I'm compiling the code with Optimisation Level None (-O0) and debug enabled. Let me check the same code with higher Optimisation Level (-Os)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Without going into your code, I would make a few general comments.

1. What exactly are you measuring? Your profiling includes both populating and scanning the data structures. Given that (presumably) populating an ordered map would take longer, measuring both works against the idea of the gains (or otherwise) of an ordered map. Figure out what you are measuring and just measure that.
2. You also have a lot going on in the code that is probably incidental to what you are profiling: there is a lot of object creation, string concatenation, etc etc. This is probably what you are actually measuring. Focus on profiling only what your want to measure (see point 1).
3. 10,000 cases is way too small. At this scale other considerations can overwhelm what you are measuring, particularly when you are measuring everything.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I've improved my code based on your suggestions, now I am trying make this code faster, as it takes 40% CPU in my app.

Answer (score 5):

There is a reason we like getting [minimal, complete and verifiable](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) examples. Here's my code:

```
#include <map>
#include <unordered_map>
#include <stdio.h>

struct Property {
    int a;
};

static const unsigned long num_iter = 100000;
int main() {
    printf("Performance Summery:\n");
    clock_t tStart = clock();
    std::unordered_map<int, Property> myumap;

    for (int i = 0; i < num_iter; i++) {
        int ind = rand() % 1000;
        Property p;
        //p.fileName = "hello" + to_string(i) + "world!";
        p.a = i;
        myumap.insert(std::pair<int, Property> (ind, p));
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < num_iter; i++) {
        int ind = rand() % 1000;
        myumap.find(ind);
    }

    printf("Time taken unordered_map: %.2fs\n", (double)(clock() - tStart)/CLOCKS_PER_SEC);

    tStart = clock();
    std::map<int, Property> mymap;

    for (int i = 0; i < num_iter; i++) {
        int ind = rand() % 1000;
        Property p;
        //p.fileName = "hello" + to_string(i) + "world!";
        p.a = i;
        mymap.insert(std::pair<int, Property> (ind, p));
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < num_iter; i++) {
        int ind = rand() % 1000;
        mymap.find(ind);
    }

    printf("Time taken map: %.2fs\n", (double)(clock() - tStart)/CLOCKS_PER_SEC);
}
```

Run time is:

```
Performance Summery:
Time taken unordered_map: 0.04s
Time taken map: 0.07s
```

Please note that I am running 10 times the number of iterations you were running.

I suspect there are two problems with your version. The first is that you are running too little iterations for it to make a difference. The second is that you are doing expensive string operations inside the counted loop. The time it takes to run the string operations is greater than the time saved by using unordered map, hence you not seeing the difference in performance.

Comment: How did you compile this?

Comment: `g++ -std=c++11 so.cpp -o so -O3`. Actually, original compile was without -O3, but with it (and multiplying number of iterations by 10 yet again), the ratio remains.

Comment: I am surprised there is any difference at all, since that code should be optimized out.

Comment: There are limits to what the optimizer can see, apparently.

Comment: For MSVC15 adding #include <ctime>

Answer (score 2):

Whether a tree (`std::map`) or a hash map (`std::unordered_map`) is faster really depends on the number of entries and the characteristics of the key (the variability of the values, the compare and hashing functions, etc.)

But *in theory*, **a tree is slower than a hash map** because insertion and searching inside a binary tree is **O(log2(N))** complexity while insertion and searching inside a hash map is *roughly* **O(1)** complexity.

Your test didn't show it because:

1. You call `rand()` in a loop. That takes ages in comparison with the map insertion. And it generates different values for the two maps you're testing, skewing results even further. Use a lighter-weight generator e.g. a `minstd` LCG.
2. You need a higher resolution clock and more iterations so that each test run takes at least a *few hundred milliseconds*.
3. You need to make sure the compiler does not *reorder your code* so the timing calls happen where they should. This is not always easy. A memory fence around the timed test usually helps to solve this.
4. Your `find()` calls have a high probability of being optimized away since you're not using their value (I just happen to know that at least GCC in -O2 mode doesn't do that, so I leave it as is).
5. String concatenation is also very slow in comparison.

Here's my updated version:

```
#include <atomic>
#include <chrono>
#include <iostream>
#include <map>
#include <random>
#include <string>
#include <unordered_map>

using namespace std;
using namespace std::chrono;

struct Property {
  string fileName;
};

const int nIter = 1000000;

template<typename MAP_TYPE>
long testMap() {
  std::minstd_rand rnd(12345);
  std::uniform_int_distribution<int> testDist(0, 1000);
  auto tm1 = high_resolution_clock::now();
  atomic_thread_fence(memory_order_seq_cst);
  MAP_TYPE mymap;

  for (int i = 0; i < nIter; i++) {
    int ind = testDist(rnd);
    Property p;
    p.fileName = "hello" + to_string(i) + "world!";
    mymap.insert(pair<int, Property>(ind, p));
  }
  atomic_thread_fence(memory_order_seq_cst);

  for (int i = 0; i < nIter; i++) {
    int ind = testDist(rnd);
    mymap.find(ind);
  }

  atomic_thread_fence(memory_order_seq_cst);
  auto tm2 = high_resolution_clock::now();
  return (long)duration_cast<milliseconds>(tm2 - tm1).count();
}

int main()
{
  printf("Performance Summary:\n");
  printf("Time taken unordered_map: %ldms\n", testMap<unordered_map<int, Property>>());
  printf("Time taken map: %ldms\n", testMap<map<int, Property>>());
}
```

[Compiled with `-O2`](http://rextester.com/RZEB28573), it gives the following results:

```
Performance Summary:
Time taken unordered_map: 348ms
Time taken map: 450ms
```

So using `unordered_map` in *this particular case* is faster by ~20-25%.

Answer (score 1):

It's not just the lookup that's faster with an unordered_map. This slightly modified test also compares the fill times.

I have made a couple of modifications:

1. increased sample size
2. both maps now use the same sequence of random numbers.

-

```
#include <map>
#include <unordered_map>
#include <vector>
#include <stdio.h>

struct Property {
    int a;
};

struct make_property : std::vector<int>::const_iterator
{
    using base_class = std::vector<int>::const_iterator;
    using value_type = std::pair<const base_class::value_type, Property>;
    using base_class::base_class;

    decltype(auto) get() const {
        return base_class::operator*();
    }

    value_type operator*() const
    {
        return std::pair<const int, Property>(get(), Property());
    }
};

int main() {
    printf("Performance Summary:\n");
    static const unsigned long num_iter = 9999999;

    std::vector<int> keys;
    keys.reserve(num_iter);
    std::generate_n(std::back_inserter(keys), num_iter, [](){ return rand() / 10000; });


    auto time = [](const char* message, auto&& func)
    {
        clock_t tStart = clock();
        func();
        clock_t tEnd = clock();
        printf("%s: %.2gs\n", message, double(tEnd - tStart) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC);
    };

    std::unordered_map<int, Property > myumap;
    time("fill unordered map", [&]
    {
        myumap.insert (make_property(keys.cbegin()),
                       make_property(keys.cend()));
    });


    std::map<int, Property > mymap;
    time("fill ordered map",[&]
         {
             mymap.insert(make_property(keys.cbegin()),
                          make_property(keys.cend()));
         });

    time("find in unordered map",[&]
         {
             for (auto k : keys) { myumap.find(k); }
         });

    time("find in ordered map", [&]
         {
             for (auto k : keys) { mymap.find(k); }
         });
}
```

example output:

```
Performance Summary:
fill unordered map: 3.5s
fill ordered map: 7.1s
find in unordered map: 1.7s
find in ordered map: 5s
```